# random en javascript

Tags: javascript, funciones, random

me gustaría saber como hago para que javascript me ejecute lo siguiente, el programa me muestra literal lo que puse (EJEMPLO texto_aleatorio2() teniendo en cuenta que el aleatorio es 2) pero yo quiero que se ejecute la función del texto aleatorio

```
<!DOCTYPE>

<html>

<head>

  <SCRIPT language=JavaScript>

function ejemplo2() {
 var aleatorio = Math.round(Math.random()*4);

 var nombre = "texto_aleatorio"+aleatorio+"()";

document.write(nombre);



function texto_aleatorio1() { 
   var textos = new Array() 
   textos[0] = "Tenemos los mejores productos del mercado, con controles de    calidad intensivos." 
   textos[1] = "Distribuimos en todo el mundo con los mejores tiempos de    entrega y fiabilidad de los envíos." 
   textos[2] = "No tenemos competidores que nos hagan sombra. Contrate con    nosotros y compuébelo. Así de fácil." 
   textos[3] = "Disponga del mejor servicio de atención al cliente y una    respuesta rápida a sus problemas." 
   textos[4] = "Los mejores servicios, productos y, como no, los menores    precios. Todo son ventajas." 

   aleat = Math.random()  * (textos.length) 
   aleat = Math.floor(aleat) 

document.write(textos[aleat]) 
}


function texto_aleatorio2(){ 
   var textos = new Array() 
   textos[0] = " mejores productos del mercado, con controles de    calidad intensivos." 
   textos[1] = " en todo el mundo con los mejores tiempos de    entrega y fiabilidad de los envíos." 
   textos[2] = " competidores que nos hagan sombra. Contrate con    nosotros y compuébelo. Así de fácil." 
   textos[3] = " del mejor servicio de atención al cliente y una    respuesta rápida a sus problemas." 
   textos[4] = " servicios, productos y, como no, los menores    precios. Todo son ventajas." 

   aleat = Math.random() * (textos.length) 
   aleat = Math.floor(aleat) 

document.write(textos[aleat]) 
}

function texto_aleatorio3(){ 
   var textos = new Array() 
   textos[0] = " mejores productos del mercado, con controles de    calidad intensivos." 
   textos[1] = " en todo el mundo con los mejores tiempos de    entrega y fiabilidad de los envíos." 
   textos[2] = " competidores que nos hagan sombra. Contrate con    nosotros y compuébelo. Así de fácil." 
   textos[3] = " del mejor servicio de atención al cliente y una    respuesta rápida a sus problemas." 
   textos[4] = " servicios, productos y, como no, los menores    precios. Todo son ventajas." 

   aleat = Math.random() * (textos.length) 
   aleat = Math.floor(aleat) 

document.write(textos[aleat]) 
}
}
        </SCRIPT>


</head>

 <body>

     <INPUT onclick=ejemplo2() type=button value="Ejemplo 2">


 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrar dónde llamas a la función?

Comment: @FranciscoRomero  utilice un 

              <INPUT onclick=ejemplo2() type=button value="Ejemplo 2">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si no te he entendido mal lo que pretendes es ejecutar una función u otra en base a un número aleatorio.

Lo que puedes hacer es crearte un array de funciones y seleccionar la función calculando el índice aleatoriamente:

```js
function ejemplo2() {
 var aleatorio = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
  
 var texto = texto_aleatorio[aleatorio](); 
 
 document.getElementById('texto').innerText = texto;
}

var texto_aleatorio = [];

texto_aleatorio[0] = function() { 
   var textos = new Array(); 
   textos[0] = "Tenemos los mejores productos del mercado, con controles de    calidad intensivos."; 

   textos[1] = "Distribuimos en todo el mundo con los mejores tiempos de    entrega y fiabilidad de los envíos."; 

   textos[2] = "No tenemos competidores que nos hagan sombra. Contrate con    nosotros y compuébelo. Así de fácil.";
 
   textos[3] = "Disponga del mejor servicio de atención al cliente y una    respuesta rápida a sus problemas."; 

   var aleat = Math.random()  * (textos.length); 
   aleat = Math.floor(aleat); 

    return textos[aleat]; 
};

texto_aleatorio[1] = function(){ 
   var textos = new Array();
   textos[0] = " mejores productos del mercado, con controles de    calidad intensivos.";
   textos[1] = " en todo el mundo con los mejores tiempos de    entrega y fiabilidad de los envíos."; 
   textos[2] = " competidores que nos hagan sombra. Contrate con    nosotros y compuébelo. Así de fácil."; 
   textos[3] = " del mejor servicio de atención al cliente y una    respuesta rápida a sus problemas."; 

   var aleat = Math.random() * (textos.length);
   aleat = Math.floor(aleat);

   return textos[aleat]; 
}

document.getElementById('prueba').addEventListener('click', ejemplo2);
```

```html
<button id="prueba">Prueba</button>
<div id="texto"></div>
```

Comment: muchísimas gracias!!!!!  me sirvió a la maravilla

Answer (score 0):

Creo que esto es lo que quieres hacer. Hice unos ajustes al código para que aunque varies el tamaño del array el numero aleatorio que se genere nunca sobre pase el limite.

```js
var textos = new Array()
textos[0] = " mejores productos del mercado, con controles de    calidad intensivos.";
textos[1] = " en todo el mundo con los mejores tiempos de    entrega y fiabilidad de los envíos.";
textos[2] = " competidores que nos hagan sombra. Contrate con    nosotros y compuébelo. Así de fácil.";
textos[3] = " del mejor servicio de atención al cliente y una    respuesta rápida a sus problemas.";
textos[4] = " Megaman es xevere!";
textos[5] = " Me gusta el basquet";

function aleatorio() {
  document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = "";//Limpia el mensaje anterior
  nro = Math.floor(Math.random() * (textos.length - 0) + 0);//obtienes el valor aleatorio siempre acorde al tamaño de tu array
  document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = textos[nro];//imprime resultado


}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <button onclick="aleatorio()"> ejecutar </button>
  <div id="resultado"></div>
</body>


</html>
```