# ¿Como puedo obtener valores random de un array hasta que se acaben lo elementos del mismo?

Tags: javascript

El caso es que quiero obtener mediante un **loop** valores random de un **array** hasta que los mismos se acaben.

Todos los **array** cuentan con **7** valores en total y, al final, lo que quiero conseguir es obtener una combinación de dicho valores de forma automática para generar frases del mismo modo.

Lo que quiero es que esos valores ***colours, countrys y days*** sean ordenados de forma aleatoria.

Éste es el **loop** utilizado por si sirve de algo:

```js
var colours = ["White", "Red", "Black", "Purple", "Grey", "Yellow", "Blue"];
var countrys = ["Japan", "Korea", "Spain", "England", "China", "Singapur","Rumania"];
var days = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]; 
    
for (var n = 0; n < colours.length; n++) {
        document.write("My " + (n+1) + " choice is " + colours[n] + " in " + countrys[n] + " on " + days[n] + "<br>");
}
```

Comment: Posible duplicado de [random en javascript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/78035/random-en-javascript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes determinar que al realizar el bucle tome elementos aleatorios de cada array por ejemplo:

`colours[Math.floor(Math.random() * colours.length)]` , obtendrías un elemento aleatorio del array `colours`.

Este sería una ejemplo completo:

```js
var colours = ["White", "Red", "Black", "Purple", "Grey", "Yellow", "Blue"];
var countrys = ["Japan", "Korea", "Spain", "England", "China", "Singapur","Rumania"];
var days = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"];

/*for (var n = 0; n < colours.length; n++) {
    document.write("My " + (n+1) + " choice is " + colours[n] + " in " + countrys[n] + " on " + days[n] + "<br>");
}*/


for (var n = 0; n < colours.length; n++) {
    document.write("My " + (n+1) + " choice is " + colours[Math.floor(Math.random() * colours.length)] + " in " + countrys[Math.floor(Math.random() * countrys.length)] + " on " + days[Math.floor(Math.random() * days.length)] + "<br>");
}
```

Comment: Vale mencionar que en esta solución, los valores pueden repetirse.

Answer (score 3):

Podrías crearte un método que aleatoriza los arrays y posteriormente mostrarlos como los estas haciendo.

```js
let colours = ["White", "Red", "Black", "Purple", "Grey", "Yellow", "Blue"];
let countrys = ["Japan", "Korea", "Spain", "England", "China", "Singapur","Rumania"];
let days = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]; 

function shuffle(array) {
      var j, x, i;
      //Recorremos el array del final hacia delante
      for (i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        //Generamos una posicion comprendida entre los valores de nuestro array
        j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        // Asignamos el valor de la posición actual a una variable
        x = array[i];
        //Intercambiamos los valores de las dos posiciones
        array[i] = array[j];
        array[j] = x;
      }
    }
    
    shuffle(colours);
    shuffle(countrys);
    shuffle(days);
    
    for (var n = 0; n < colours.length; n++) {
        document.write("My " + (n+1) + " choice is " + colours[n] + " in " + countrys[n] + " on " + days[n] + "<br>");
    }
```

De esta manera te aseguras que sacas una combinación de todos los valores, sin repetidos.

Answer (score 2):

En lugar de seleccionar las opciones de forma aleatoria y controlar que no se repitan podrías *ordenar los arreglos de forma aleatoria* (`eg: shuffle`)

Para esto podrías usar la versión de [`Fisher–Yates shuffle algorithm`](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/shuffle/).

### Demo:

```js
function shuffle(array) {
  var m = array.length,
    t, i;

  // While there remain elements to shuffle...
  while (m) {

    // Pick a remaining element…
    i = Math.floor(Math.random() * m--);

    // And swap it with the current element.
    t = array[m];
    array[m] = array[i];
    array[i] = t;
  }
  return array;
}

var colours = shuffle(["White", "Red", "Black", "Purple", "Grey", "Yellow", "Blue"]);
var countrys = shuffle(["Japan", "Korea", "Spain", "England", "China", "Singapur","Rumania"]);
var days = shuffle(["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]);

for (var n = 0; n < colours.length; n++) {
    document.write("My " + (n+1) + " choice is " + colours[n] + " in " + countrys[n] + " on " + days[n] + "<br>");
}
```

Comment: +1 por link a shuffle

Answer (score 1):

Otro ejemplo usando prototype

```js
Array.prototype.MostrarColor = function(){
       let i = Math.floor(Math.random() * (colours.length ));
       let Mycolor = colours[i];
        colours.splice(i,1);
        return Mycolor;
}    
Array.prototype.MostrarDia = function(){
       let i = Math.floor(Math.random() * (days.length ) );
       let MyDay = days[i];
        days.splice(i,1);
        return MyDay;
}    
       


let colours = ["White", "Red", "Black", "Purple", "Grey", "Yellow", "Blue"];
let countrys = ["Japan", "Korea", "Spain", "England", "China", "Singapur","Rumania"];
let days = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]; 


for (var n = 0; n < countrys.length; n++) {
    document.write("My " + (n+1) + " choice is " + countrys.MostrarColor() + " in " + countrys[n] + " on " + countrys.MostrarDia() + "<br>");
}
```